# How to check if symbol is class-private?

Tags: scala

There is `isPrivate`, but how do you make a function `isPrivateIn(Symbol)`?

```
trait Foo {
  private[Foo] class Moo
  class Noo
  isPrivate[Moo, Foo] //true
  isPrivate[Noo, Foo] //false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally found the method, `privateWithin`.